# How to keep Selenium webdriver minimized throughout the process?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I developed a bot to download some files in the background, while working. But every time a download is made, the webdriver screen appears on the screen and I have to manually minimize it. Any suggestion?

```
options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
            "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
           "download.default_directory":"D:\Download", 
           "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf",
           "download.prompt_for_download": False,
           "download.directory_upgrade": True,
           "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
           "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
           "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
           "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2
           })

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.copel.com/AgenciaWeb/autenticar/loginCliente.do")
```

headless is not a option in my case

Comment: What does "headless is not an option in my case" mean?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-to-minimize-the-browser-window-which-was-launched-via-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @DevanshSoni if i use headless, the download will not occour! the website i'm using to download blocks it somehow

Comment: What error are you getting using headless mode?

Comment: @KunduK if i use headless mode, the download just do not work, after de script, the folder remain empty. i tried to use a def with post, but i didn't manage to make it work

Comment: So did you click on any button to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here: [Selenium Web-driver Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=webdriver.minimize#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.minimize_window)

You can minimize or maximize your browser window using `minimize_window()` and `maximize_window()` functions.

Adding this line solves your problem:

```
driver.minimize_window()
```

But only adding this may not help if your website opens a new tab after clicking on some link. So, adding these lines will ensure that your script is working with last opened tab and not the first tab. Add these lines in your script after every click event which results in opening a new tab.

```
win_list = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(win_list[-1])
```

For example, Here, `l1` will throw Error if we don't switch to last opened tab.

```
driver.get("https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home")

l0 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/h2/font/a')
l0.click()  # This click event results in opening a new tab

win_list = driver.window_handles # This gives the list of all tabs
driver.switch_to.window(win_list[-1]) # To switch to the last tab opened

l1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/a')
l1.click()
```

Comment: It did not worked for me, when i did that, my script couldnt find the element to download the files.

Comment: Then you should try moving that browser window out of your sight by moving it to a position which can't be displayed on your monitor. Try this: `driver.set_window_position(-2000,0)`

Comment: but i'll be able to still use my computer? and work?

Comment: Sorry, this idea of moving browser window does'nt seem to work. But I've tried `minimize_window()` and it's working for me. It works in background and gives a popup asking for Download confirmation.

Comment: yeah, thats the problem, i don't want him asking for download confirmation, but when i tried the minimize_window(),  it didn't found the xpath i put on it

Comment: This happens when clicking on a button or link opens a new tab. By the way, From which website are you trying to download? The website given in your code?

Comment: yes, the link opens a new tab! from a energy website. for data analysis